# How to implement this FilteringIterator?

Tags: java, iterator

1. IObjectTest is a interface with a
   single boolean test(Object o) method
2. FilteringIterator is an implementation of Iterator which is
           initialized with another Iterator
           and an IObjectTest instance: new
           FilteringIterator(myIterator,
           myTest). Your FilteringIterator will
           then allow iteration over
           'myIterator', but skipping any
           objects which don't pass the
           'myTest' test.

Since the "hasNext" operation actually involve repeatly moving the underlying iterator 
untill reach the next matching item. The question is how can it move it iterator back since hasNext is not supposed to move the underlying iterator.

Comment: I've tagged this "homework" because the wording makes it sounds very much like it is. Leon, please correct me if it isn't!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to make your iterator stateful.  Cache the last value you retrieved from `hasNext` and use that from the `next` method, if it exists.

```
private boolean hasCached;
private T cached;

public boolean hasNext() {
   if ( hasCached ) return true;
   //iterate until you find one and set hasCached and cached
}

public T next() {
   if ( hasCached ) {
      hasCached = false;
      return cached;
   }
   //iterate until next matches
}
```

Answer (score 13):

If you want to do it yourself, you can use code similar to what I've written below. However, I do recommend you use Guava's [Iterators.filter(Iterator, Predicate)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#filter-java.util.Iterator-com.google.common.base.Predicate-)

```
public class FilteredIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private Iterator<? extends T> iterator;
    private Filter<T> filter;
    private T nextElement;
    private boolean hasNext;

    /**
     * Creates a new FilteredIterator using wrapping the iterator and returning only elements matching the filter.
     * 
     * @param iterator
     *            the iterator to wrap
     * @param filter
     *            elements must match this filter to be returned
     */
    public FilteredIterator(Iterator<? extends T> iterator, Filter<T> filter) {
        this.iterator = iterator;
        this.filter = filter;

        nextMatch();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return hasNext;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        if (!hasNext) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

        return nextMatch();
    }

    private T nextMatch() {
        T oldMatch = nextElement;

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            T o = iterator.next();

            if (filter.matches(o)) {
                hasNext = true;
                nextElement = o;

                return oldMatch;
            }
        }

        hasNext = false;

        return oldMatch;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}

public interface Filter<T> {

    /**
     * Determines whether elements should be filtered or not.
     * 
     * @param element the element to be matched against the filter
     * @return {@code true} if the element matches the filter, otherwise {@code false}
     */
    public boolean matches(T element);
}
```

Comment: No, so I've updated to code to delegate the remove call to the backing iterator. Good call!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `remove` method won't work. It will remove the next element, not the current one.

Answer (score 5):

If this is homework, this won't help you, but if not: the [Guava Library](https://github.com/google/guava) has the exact functionality you are after

[`Iterators.filter(Iterator, Predicate)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#filter-java.util.Iterator-com.google.common.base.Predicate-)

(You might have a look at [how they did it](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.java#L626) for inspiration)

Answer (score 0):

how about my version? the next() method could be a little easy to understand compare to the previous examples.

```
public class PredicateIterator implements Iterator {

private Iterator iterator;
private Predicate predicate;
private Object cached;
private boolean hasNextCached;
private boolean hasNext;

public PredicateIterator(Iterator iterator, Predicate predicate) {
    this.iterator = iterator;
    this.predicate = predicate;
}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    if (hasNextCached) {
        return hasNext;
    } else {
        return findNextMatch();
    }
}

private boolean findNextMatch() {
    boolean match = false;
    while(!match && iterator.hasNext()) {
        cached = iterator.next();
        match = predicate.test(cached);
    }
    hasNextCached = true;
    hasNext = match;
    return match;
}

@Override
public Object next() {
    if (hasNext()) {
        hasNextCached = false;
        return cached;
    } else {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
}

@Override
public void remove() {
    iterator.remove();
}
```

}