# How to implement Filtering Iterator in Java?

Tags: java, iterator, filtering

I have created an array (tab[]) of objects and now I need to filter and print via one of their fields (ex. print if ob.a>1 ). I created an Iterator interface, ArrayIterator that goes through all entries on list and Predicate interface. This is constructor of my FilteringIterator:

```
private final Iterator iterf;
private final Predicate pred; 
public FilteringIterator(ArrayIterator i, Predicate predykat) 
{ 
    iterf=i;
    pred=predykat;
    iterf.first();
}
```

Method that prints every entry using my "basic" iterator looks like this:

```
  public void printlist()
{
    ArrayIterator itab =new ArrayIterator(lista);
    for(itab.first();!itab.isDone(); itab.next())
    {
        Student stud=(Student)itab.current();
        stud.show();
    }
}
```

I also have a class that implements Predicate interface:

```
public interface Predicate

 {
      public boolean accept(Object ob); 
 }
```

How to use my FilteringIterator, when it requires Predicate, and I cannot create such object, as it's an interface?

Comment: Create a class that implements `Predicate`, and create an instance of the class.

Comment: Are you asking [how to implement an interface in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement this FilteringIterator?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5474893/5221149)

Comment: Would have been helpful to see client code which iterated through your custom list since I don’t understand how filtered iterator is passed via constructor; usually we do myList.iterator() to get implementation of iterator to iterate through elements

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement this FilteringIterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474893/how-to-implement-this-filteringiterator)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to implement `next()` in `FilteringIterator` class.
It should be something like:

```
public T next() {
    T next = iterf.next();
    while (!pred.accept(next))
        next = iterf.next();
    return next;
}
```

Now that you see `next()` it should be an easy exercise to implement `hasNext()` as well!

In order to create a predicate you should implement Predicate interface, for example:

```
class MyPredicate implements Predicate {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(Object ob){
        if (!ob instanceof Student)
            return false;

        Student student = (Student) ob;
        return student.a > 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: What about `hasNext()`?

Comment: @dnault it would be nice to implement - but it wasn't part of the question... Second, after seeing how `next` is implemented - it shouldn't be too difficult to do similar thing for `hasNext`.

Comment: This answer helped, I didnt create an object implementing Predicate.